# Can any website secured using TLS can be impersonated using a rogue certificate issued by a rogue CA?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

> Any website secured using TLS can be impersonated using a rogue certificate issued by a rogue CA. This is irrespective of which CA issued the website’s true certificate and of any property of that certificate.
>
> — Marc Stevens et al. 2009

Is this still true?

I understand one purpose of [Certificate Transparency](http://www.certificate-transparency.org/) is to eventually detect rogue CAs in the long run. But is there any protection against the immediate attack?

Comment: If not, how was Diginotar exposed?

Answer (score 4):

Ironically enough, [X.509 certificates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) *can* theoretically be scoped to specific domains and sub-domains, through the [Name Constraints](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10) extension: if a CA certificate contains a `Name Constraints` extension with a `permittedSubtrees` field containing a `dNSName` of value `example.com` may issue certificates only if the host names appearing in the `Subject Alt Names` extensions of these certificate are from the example.com domain or a sub-domain thereof. This constraint propagates down the chain, so that certificates emitted by sub-CA must also comply.

Unfortunately, this scheme fails in practice, for two reasons:

- When the server's certificate does not include a `Subject Alt Name` extension at all, SSL clients have the habit of using the Common Name from the `subjectDN` as a substitute. As per the X.509 rules, the Common Name is *not* covered by the `Name Constraints` of type `dNSName`. Using the Common Name is explicitly allowed by [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1).
- Nobody implements support for `Name Constraints`. If you don't mark the extension as critical, then clients will ignore it. If you do mark the extension as critical, then clients will reject the certificate. Thus, you cannot really use them.

The lack of support implies that nobody tries to scope certificates with `Name Constraints`. Since nobody tries, implementers have no incentive to actually implement the support.

---

The overall consequence is that CA are, currently, not scoped. Therefore, any root CA trusted by SSL clients, and any intermediate CA issued (directly or not) by one of these root CA, will be technically trusted for validating SSL server certificates for every possible domain name.

Nevertheless, rogue CA are a quite rare occurrence. The reason is that a forged certificate, with a fake name, also points quite clearly at the CA that issued it. Faking certificates is very risky for a CA; there is a quasi-certainty of getting caught after the fact. Root CA get included in OS and browsers by signing contracts that impose severe penalties on misbehaviour; when root CA issue sub-CA certificates, they again contractually impose the same kind of penalties. We are talking about millions of dollars here.

Actual cases of fake certificates are mostly due to compromises, transient in nature, and happen about once per year.

Comment: +1. Nevertheless our current system will collapse like a house of cards if there's ever a cyberwar. As relying on incentives will only go so far.

Answer (score 3):

There is potential protection in the form of certificate pinning.  This can be done in an application, and some browsers (hopefully all in the future) support it in the form of certificate pinning.   Certificate pinning can take two forms, first, you can submit the fingerprint for your certificate to the browser vendors (Google and Mozilla, currently) to be included in the browser itself.   Secondly, you can add the pins to an HSTS header, which will tell browsers that have visited your site in the past if the cert they're now seeing is kosher or not.

Because certificate pinning happens at the individual certificate level, it mitigates the threat of certificates signed by malicious or compromised roots.

Comment: I've found that various large organisations actually rely on the commutability of SSL certificates to load balance encryption behind the scenes and various forms of what they consider are "ok" XSS behaviour. When running a browser-level addon for certificate pinning I've found that visiting the same site on the same day or hour will randomly serve different SSL certificates so far as serial numbers are concerned.

Answer (score 2):

All a site needs to do is to present a certificate signed by a trusted CA.  There is currently no way to "scope" CAs (limiting what origins they can sign certificates for) nor is there a way for a site to specify which CAs are valid for it.  (And even if there were, this is a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem, how would you know that information is valid?)

So, the answer is basically: yes, any CA can sign a certificate for any site.

Comment: After a CA was found to have signed inappropriate certificates, Chrome started only trusting them for a handful of level two domains, so for a very limited set of CA there is partial trust. This was due to unilateral action, nothing in the technical specification. See http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.nz/2014/07/maintaining-digital-certificate-security.html